# Replacing part of string in a column with exceptions

Tags: pandas, regex-group

I am doing a data cleaning in Jupyter Notebook with Pandas and I am trying to get just first part of the string. But there is a catch. I can easily delete rest of the expression but some fields are actually valid. So for example in the column:

| SHIPMENT_PROVIDER |
| --- |
| Usps |
| Usps International |
| Uspsxy3 |
| Usps7kju |
| Usps0by |

So I want to keep Usps and Usps international. So far I used following code for simpler challenges:

```
orders.loc[:, 'SHIPMENT_PROVIDER'] = orders.loc[:, 'SHIPMENT_PROVIDER'].replace(to_replace='(?:Usps)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$', value = 'Usps', regex = True)
```

But this won't work with two alternative expressions. So the idea that  Usps with some random characters e.g.(Uspsxyz) should be replaced by Usps, but Usps International with some random characters e.g. (Usps Internationalxyz) should be replaced by Usps International.

Comment: What do you mean by `But this won't work with two alternative expressions` Can you update the question with an example that should work, and with the expected result?

Comment: You are right I am sorry I wasn't clear enough. So Usps with some random characters e.g.(Uspsxyz) should be replaced by Usps, but Usps International with some random characters e.g. (Usps Internationalxyz) should be replaced by Usps International.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a pattern, you could use a capture group for the first part instead with an optional part for International

```
^(Usps)(?: International)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

In the replacement use group 1.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MJxNAx/1)

```
import pandas as pd

pattern = r"^(Usps)(?: International)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"

items = [
    "Usps",
    "Usps International",
    "Uspsxy3",
    "Usps7kju",
    "Usps0by",
    "Usps Internationalxyz"
]

orders = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=["SHIPMENT_PROVIDER"])
orders.loc[:, 'SHIPMENT_PROVIDER'] = orders.loc[:, 'SHIPMENT_PROVIDER'].replace(r"^(Usps)(?: International)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", r"\1", regex=True)
print(orders)
```

Output

```
    SHIPMENT_PROVIDER
0                Usps
1  Usps International
2                Usps
3                Usps
4                Usps
5                Usps
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have posted regex solutions. How about a non-regex solution:

```py
s = orders["SHIPMENT_PROVIDER"]
orders["SHIPMENT_PROVIDER"] = np.select(
    [s.str.startswith("Usps International"), s.str.startswith("Usps")],
    ["Usps International", "Usps"],
    s,
)
```

Comment: Thank you. But I might not have been clear enough. I edited the questions. Basically Usps(xyz) should be replaced by Usps but Usps International(xyz) should be relaced by Usps International.